# Why it is not storing all the key values rather it is storing the last updated value?

Tags: java, file-io

Using the below code I am able to store in the properties file, but the problem is it is storing the last stored value. I mean if a am stoing values `val1`, `val2`, `val3`...`val5` it is storing only `var5` value not others...Is there any way to do it?

```
    prop = new Properties();

    try {  
           /* //set the properties value  
            prop.setProperty(Key, value);  

            System.out.println("Updating the value for:"+Key);
            //save properties to project testdata.properties file
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "xyz.properties"), null);  */

        file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "\\src\\test\\java\\config\\testdata123.properties");
        Properties table = new Properties();

        table.setProperty(Key, value);

        System.out.println("Properties has been set in HashTable:" + table);

        System.out.println("The Key values are :" + value);
        //saving the properties in file
        saveProperties(table);

        System.out.println("After the change in HashTable:" + table);
        //saving the properties in file


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "Fail" + "While updating the testdata.properties file";
    }

    return "Pass";
}

public static void saveProperties(Properties p) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(file);
    p.store(fr, "Properties");
    System.out.println("After saving properties:" + p);
}

static void loadProperties(Properties p) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
    p.load(fi);
    fi.close();

    System.out.println("After Loading properties:" + p);
}
```

The Full code:

```
   public static String setPropertiesValue(String Key, String value) {

    try {
        file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "\\src\\test\\java\\config\\xyz.properties");
        Properties table = new Properties();

        table.load(new FileInputStream(file));

        table.setProperty(Key, value);

        System.out.println("Properties has been set in HashTable:" + table);

        System.out.println("The Key values are :" + value);
        //saving the properties in file
        saveProperties(table);

        System.out.println("After the change in HashTable:" + table);
        //saving the properties in file


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "Fail" + "While updating the testdata.properties file";
    }

    return "Pass";
}

public static void saveProperties(Properties p) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(file);
    p.store(fr, "Properties");

    System.out.println("After saving properties:" + p);
}

static void loadProperties(Properties p) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
    p.load(fi);
    fi.close();

    System.out.println("After Loading properties:" + p);
}
enter code here
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you are creating a new Properties called  'table' and overwriting your File every time you save the Properties into a File. Instead load the Properties from an existing file and set the new key,value and save it.
    Hope this should work!

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class Test {
        static File file = null;

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            setPropertiesValue("name1", "value1");
            setPropertiesValue("name2", "value2");
            setPropertiesValue("name3", "value3");
            setPropertiesValue("name4", "value4");
            setPropertiesValue("name5", "value5");
        }

        public static String setPropertiesValue(String Key, String value) {

            try {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\config\\xyz.properties");

                Properties table = new Properties();

                table.load(new FileInputStream(file));

                table.setProperty(Key, value);

                System.out.println("Properties has been set in HashTable:" + table);

                System.out.println("The Key values are :" + value);
                // saving the properties in file
                saveProperties(table);

                System.out.println("After the change in HashTable:" + table);
                // saving the properties in file

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return "Fail" + "While updating the testdata.properties file";
            }

            return "Pass";
        }

        public static void saveProperties(Properties p) throws IOException {
            FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(file);
            p.store(fr, "Properties");

            System.out.println("After saving properties:" + p);
        }

        static void loadProperties(Properties p) throws IOException {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
            p.load(fi);
            fi.close();

            System.out.println("After Loading properties:" + p);
        }
    }
```

The result (value) of the properties file is as follows

## Properties

## Thu Mar 13 12:18:25 GMT 2014

name5=value5
name4=value4
name3=value3
name2=value2
name1=value1
Is this what you are trying to get as the result? or Am I missing something?

Comment: I did not get you..Can you please update my code here so that i will able to understand?

Comment: add this line  table.load(new FileInputStream(file)); below the line where you are creating the Properties called 'table'.

Comment: Can you paste your full code please? I can't see how are you calling the method that updates the Properties!